# How to filter out results on OneToMany relation in Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a list:

- Category 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
- Category 2

  - Item 3
  - Item 1
- Category 3

  - Item 5
  - Item 2

So the following tables are created:

Category

```php
    class Category
    {
        ...


        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $weight;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        private $isDeleted;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CategoryItemMapping", mappedBy="category")
         */
        private $categoryItemMapping;
    }
```

Item

```php
    class Item
    {
        ...


        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        private $isDeleted;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        private $isPublic;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CategoryItemMapping", mappedBy="item")
         */
        private $categoryItemMapping;
    }
```

CategoryItemMapping

```php
    class CategoryItemMapping
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $weight;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="categoryItemMapping")
         */
        private $category;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="categoryItemMapping")
         */
        private $item;
    }
```

and the query builder I made so far:

```php
$query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, cim')
    ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.categoryItemMapping', 'cim')
    ->leftJoin('cim.item', 'i')
    ->andWhere('c.isDeleted = false AND ((i.id IS NOT NULL AND i.isDeleted = false AND i.isPublic = true) OR (i.id IS NULL))')
    ->addOrderBy('c.weight', 'asc')
    ->addOrderBy('cim.weight', 'asc')
;
```

The goal is to show all categories `c` that are nod deleted `c.isDeleted = false`, and inside the categories, show all items `i` that are not deleted `i.isDeleted = false` and are public `i.isPublic = true`.

The problem with the above query is that it does not show categories containing only deleted items or containing only items that are not public.

So, how can I better control what should be output in `OneToMany` relation within one query builder?

Comment: Maybe I missundertood something but I don't get the point to have the entity CategoryItemMapping. Why not only Item with many-to-one unidirectional Items (avoiding coupling)

Comment: Query could be something like: $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c,i')
    ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Item', 'i', 'WITH', 'i.category = c.id')
    ->andWhere('c.isDeleted = false AND i.isDeleted = false')
    ->addOrderBy('c.weight', 'asc')
    ->addOrderBy('i.weight', 'asc'); I havent tried the query but I think it is a good starting point.

Comment: @josecash, the CategoryItemMapping is necessary because it contains information about the `weight` (position on the list) and `Item` can belong to many categories as shown on the example

Comment: @josecash the query you have given is not the way to go, because in your example empty categories won't show up, so it needs something a bit more sophisticated